# jquery - bootstrap datetimepicker viewMode months format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using the jquery plugin bootstrap datetimepicker and I want to set the full format of months in the calendar. How i can do that because I didn't any function that allow me to do this ?

```
<div id="datetimepicker"></div>

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'fr',
    dayViewHeaderFormat: 'YYYY',
    viewMode: 'months',
    format: "MMMM YYYY", 
    debug : true
});
```

[image]

Comment: The plugin does not seem to allow full months in the `months` viewMode you would have to either modify the plugin or replace the text;

Comment: @SamBattat any other solutions without modify the plugin ?!

Comment: There is always a way.. check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use moment.js to locate the language and get the list of full months, or alternatively, specify `months` manually as an array of all months.

Listen to the `dp.show` event and loop through the months text replacing it with corresponding full month's text.

```
moment.locale('fr');
var months = moment.months();

$('#datetimepicker10').datetimepicker({
    viewMode: 'months',
    locale: 'fr'
}).on('dp.show', function(e){
    var $dp = $(e.target);
    var $cal = $('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget', $dp);
    $('.month', $cal).each(function(i){
        $(this).text(months[i]);
    });
});
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/nepek6u8/